# Iteration over the same automated test case

Tags: selenium, iteration, testng

I am using selenium webdriver and testNG to create automated test case. I am running the same test case multiple times for different set of data. The execution is slowing down after each iteration and at some point it becomes very slow and the process stops. 
The code is very straightforward: iterating over the same testNG method containing selenese scripts (example:driver.findElement(By.id(target)).click();)
Any idea why the execution is getting slower and after multiple iterations it stops.

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing the code.

Comment: Yes, please show us the test method and how you iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

@Anna Clearing temp files solved a similar issue for me. My test was generating a lot of log files, screenshots, windows temp files, among others. Now I make automation clear my temp files and my results have been way better.

If that does not solve your issue, please share more information on how your automation is setup (testNG, Jenkins, Maven, etc) and the code that initiates the runs.

Comment: Also try increasing your 'Java Heap Memory' size. This way your program has more breathing space.

Make sure you're program/script is not blocking too much 'memory heap'.